# How do I calculate the result of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is given: $\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{50}  + \frac{1}{375}  + \frac{1}{2500}  + ...+\frac{1}{k}\times 5^{-k}$ ?
I'm interested in steps, too. I've tried to rewrite it using well known series but I have not succeded.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the geometric series.
Integrate both sides (the constant turns out to be zero), the left hand side is $-\ln(1-x)$ , do you see why there is a negative up front?
Now let $x=1/5$ and you get your result. You can work it out now

Comment: we need $k\to\infty$ for $\ln(1-x)$ (+1) though

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I kind of assumed that it is an infinite series...